# Find determinant of matrix $a_{ij} = 1$ if $i<j-1,$ $a_{ij} = 0$ if $i=j-1,$ $a_{ij} = -1$ if $i>j-1.$

Tags: matrices, induction, determinant

Let $A$ be a square matrix of size $n$ with 
$$a_{ij} = \begin{cases} \phantom{+}1 & \text{if } i<j-1, \\
\phantom{+}0 & \text{if } i=j-1, \\
-1 & \text{if } i>j-1.\end{cases}$$
I'm asked to find the determinant of $A$ with the hint of using induction. 
I check some values: 
$$n=2 \implies |A| = 1$$
$$n=3 \implies |A| = -1$$
$$n=4 \implies |A| = 1$$
I seems that $|A| = (-1)^n$ (as a side note I know this is true).

So let's assume $n=2$ is my base case and let $|A|_n$ denote determinant of matrix $A$ of size $n$.

I need to prove that $|A|_{n+1} = (-1)\cdot|A|_n$, but this is where I get stuck. I've tried using expansion along a row, 
$$|A| = \sum_{j}a_{ij}A_{ij}$$
which seems promising if I start at the bottom right ($a_{nn} = -1$ for all $n$ and $A_{ij}$ is the previous determinant). But I can't find a pattern for the rest of that sum, the rest should equal zero.

How can I prove this using induction and beginner matrix theory?

Comment: Hint: write a $4\times 4$ matrix and the corresponding $A_{i,j}$. also write say $A_{3,5}$ for a $5\times5$ matrix. What do you know about determinant if any of columns (rows) is a linear combination of the other columns (rows)? In particular, do you happen to see the same column or row?

Comment: @Andrei Thanks I've got it now :)

Answer (score 0):

$$
A_n=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc|c}
-1& 0& 1& \cdots&\cdots&1\\
-1&-1& 0& \ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\
\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\
\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&0&1\\
-1&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&-1&0\\
\hline
-1&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&-1&-1
\end{array}\right)
=\pmatrix{A_{n-1}&u\\ -\mathbf1^T&-1}.
$$
Subtract the last row of $A_n$ by the last but one row, we get $\det(A_n)=\det\pmatrix{A_{n-1}&u\\ 0&-1}=-\det(A_{n-1})$.